# How can you let Google Calendar enforce a maximum number of meetings a day (ie similar to Kanban)

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

As a manager I always ask people to check my Calendar (which is up to date) and feel free to schedule a meeting. The problem with this is that I regularly end up with days where I'm doing back to back meetings (sometimes this of my own making: I schedule too many meetings for myself on the same day).

Is there a setting on google calendar (or an add-on, for that matter) that rejects new meetings with me that go beyond a certain *number* of meetings/events a day? For example suppose my limit is 3 meetings a day, then when a recruiter for example tries to schedule a fourth meeting, a polite error message saying something like:

> This meeting proposal exceeds the maximum number of allowed meetings per day for Mr. John Doe.

Comment: Please add more details. Are you using a gmail.com or a Google Workspace account? Have you heard about Google Workspace Individual? Is it available in your country? Have you considered to use Google Apps Script / Google Chat bot to help you with your appointment management? P.S. Asking for software recommendations, including add-ons, is off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any plug-in or setting that can do this in Google Calendar. That's why I use calendly. I configured the times of the day I accept meetings in and the maximum number of meetings per day.

Hope that helps.